# How to find the name of the server you are on in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

When I develop a shiny package locally I pull from local sources and when I upload the ui.r and server.r files I need to change the paths of things.

Is there a way I can find out which server I am on in shiny?

That way I can use an if statement to choose between paths and I don't need to manually change stuff when I upload.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [detect which computer I'm running an R script on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151355/detect-which-computer-im-running-an-r-script-on) - Sys.info()['nodename']

Comment: Look at the `session$clientData` object